# Use default scope ordering with a model::findAllBySql() call

Tags: yii

I have `defaultScope()` defined in my model class X to

```
return (array('order'=>'title ASC'));
```

When I run a `findAllBySql()` as follows:

```
 X::model()->findAllBySql(
   'SELECT *
      FROM x
     WHERE x.id NOT IN (
        SELECT y.x_id
          FROM y
         WHERE y.id = :y_id
        )',
   array(
    'mf_list_id'=>$y->id,
   )
 );
```

I was hoping to see the returned members of X in order ascending title. Unfortunately this does not appear to be the case.

Is there any way to use the default scope with this query? I am dynamically constructing the sql, so simply adding an order clause or criteria to the `findAllBySql()` call is undesirable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAllBySql()` internally [calls](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L1574) `resetScopes()` so it cannot be done, only if you clone and roll your own `findAllBySql`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this, I settled on this solution:

Instead of running `findAllBySql()` I run the following:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition='
  id NOT IN (
    SELECT y.x_id
      FROM y
      WHERE y.id = :y_id
  )';
$criteria->params=(array('y_id'=>$y->id));
X::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

This uses the default scope from X and orders by title as desired.